# Proving that DEF is also an equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, congruences-geometry

[image]

The question gives that ABC is an equilateral triangle, AD = BE = CF and ∠DAB = ∠EBC.

I tried using only cases of triangle congruences to prove it, but **I'm not sure if I did it correctly**. Thus, take a look at my proof and **tell me if everything is okay or not, please**.

***Here's my attempt:***

Since AB = CB, BE = AD and ∠DAB = ∠EBC, then I have that **ADB and BEC are congruent triangles by SAS**.

- By the way, **CF = BE (question gives)** which is the same as *CE + EF = BD + DE*, but CE = BD, then EF = DE after replacing in formula.

  (2 sides equals, lefting just one to prove that they are equal - in order to get the equilateral triangle)

Now, note that **∠A = ∠B = ∠C = ∠ABD + ∠EBC**.

- However, since **∠DAB = ∠EBC**, then I have *∠A = ∠B = ∠C = ∠ABD + ∠DAB*.
- Cince triangle ADB and triangle BEC are congruent, it follows that ∠DBA = ∠ECB. So, *∠C = ∠DAB + ∠ECB*.
- Looking at ∠C especially, we have ∠C = ∠DAB + ∠ECB. However, ∠C = ∠ACF + ∠ECB. So, ∠DAB + ∠ECB = ∠ACF + ∠ECB, then ∠DAB = ∠ACF.
- Now, since AC = AB, ∠DAB = ∠ACF and CF = AD, then **ACF and BAD are congruent triangles by SAS congruence case**.
- After that, I have the 3 triangles are congruent as well.
- So since **AD = CF (question gives)** and **AF = CE** (because AFC and  , then for *AD = AF + FD* and *CF = CE + EF*, I have **FD = EF**.

**Therefore, for *EF = DE* and *FD = EF*, it follows *EF = DE = FD*.**

**By the definition of equilateral triangle, I got that DEF is also an equilateral triangle!**

I'm sorry for not only this huge proof, but also for not knowing how to use whether LaTeX or MathJax (I have bad skills) and I hope you understand that.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: ACE = 60 – ECB = 60 – ADB = EBC. Similar arguments ( used in the first paragraph) can be applied to show ED = FD.

Comment: Got it! Thanks @Mick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your proof is okay. It just can be shorter:

After finding $\Delta DAB \cong \Delta CBE$, this implies that $\angle ABE = \angle BCF$, you can simply use
$$\angle ACF + \angle BCF = \angle ABE+ \angle CBE$$
and since $\angle ABE = \angle BCF$, we have $\angle ACF = \angle CBE$. From here, you can directly conclude $\Delta ACF \cong \Delta CBE$ by **SAS** since $AC = BC$, $CF = BE$ and $\angle ACF = \angle CBE$.

Then $AF = CE = BD$ and $CF = BE = AD$ imply $EF = FE = ED$, so the result follows.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :) As I said your proof was already correct so I just shortened it. Good luck!